# iOS navigation on multiple controllers w/ storyboard

Tags: ios, interface-builder, xcode-storyboard

I have a *vertical* navigation that I want to use similar to a `TabBarController`.

In lue of my question, is it possible to set up *storyboard* `relationships` with `IB`? If not, is there any other `IB` way of going about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the research I've done, this is **not** currently possible.

What I ended up doing was only one `UIViewControler` with my navigation buttons on the left and a single `UIView` on the right. Depending on the navigation button *touched*, I "inflate" a `UIView` `XIB` using `[[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"someNib" owner:self options:nil] objectAtIndex:0]`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if i understand your question correctly. When you are in IB and have opened your storyboard you can press ctrl on your keyboard  and drag a line from one of your navigation items to the desired target view controller. IB will setup the relationship for you which is called a storyboard segue. This will handle the view controller transition.

Comment: I thought of doing things that way, but with all the view controller I have up, I end up with 10 segues coming from each controller. It turns into a mess rather quick :(

Comment: I see your point. In this case you may be better off doing it programmatically.